# gradle says, 'see compiler error output', but there isn't any

Tags: hibernate, gradle

I'm trying to build hibernate-orm from the 4.3.11.Final tag, and I get the following. Adding --info does not deliver any more info.

```
Executing task ':hibernate-core:runAnnotationProcessors' (up-to-date check took 0.157 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
:hibernate-core:runAnnotationProcessors FAILED
:hibernate-core:runAnnotationProcessors (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 3.384 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/bmargulies/hibernate-orm/source-generation.gradle' line: 305

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hibernate-core:runAnnotationProcessors'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Add -s, maybe this gives enough additional Information

Comment: `--info` or `--debug` are usually helpful.

Comment: Neither added any commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will easily get a strong clue if you remove the diagnostic listener on line 328 of `source-generation.gradle`. DISCLAIMER: This is just a hack.

This:

```
return compiler.getTask(null, null, diagnosticListener, options, null, compilationUnits);
```

Becomes:

```
return compiler.getTask(null, null, null, options, null, compilationUnits);
```

You will then get some output in the std error, e.g.:

```
\bla\bla\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\main\java\org\hibernate\hql\internal\ast\HqlSqlWalker.java:44: error: package org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr does not exist
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker;
```

I'm not a hibernate expert but googling this error message led me to a page which states:

> 4.3.x needs to be built with JDK 1.7

I guess that you are building on JDK 1.8. Drilling down into the details is beyond my hibernate knowledge :-) Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that was it. Thank you.